# How about a crossword featuring Mickey Mouse?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: The crossword]

**Across**
1. Packed and set up a tent around river's bank (7)
5. A crush of Rome? (5)
9. Suppress repeated 7 down taking? We object (4)
11. Soldier in news story, retreating: "Go back!" (7)
12. Military officer's firing is never accepted – on the contrary (6)
13. Baker, singer and songwriter ain't a suspect (5)
14. Lira replaced as currency in Middle Eastern country (4)
15. Soprano and alto leads made uniform in clean single (7)
17. Do I act poorly around high-ranking chess player, being arrogantly assertive? (8)
19. They make clothes for sportsmen playing with no big ball (9)
22. One might find present for today there for malevolent jeweller that's refused working in America (9)
25. Wrongly interprets crazy dreams one's caught in (8)
26. Dean's coworkers showing skill (7)
27. Part of the world shown by second half of film featuring Mickey Mouse (4)
28. "Integrity" and all that jazz surrounding Harvard and Imperial's entrances (5)
29. Group is to learn to conceal weapon (6)
30. Spear cut walls of castle in English city (7)
31. Brand new After Eight? (4)
32. US president is missing one day from Wednesday? (5)
33. Imprint in the blue that's of questionable quality (7)

**Down**
1. I'm following charismatic revolutionary, facing trouble for innocent individuals (8)
2. Attack state north of Illinois, destroying Madison, the capital (6)
3. Old man set up a possibly Afghan temple (6)
4. Doctor playing board game with SAS's top flyers (7)
6. Chewing gum, with no tea, for lord according to William (8)
7. Intoxicated poet has ingested, among others, laudanum? (6)
8. Bitter criminal stealing uranium in retro crime drama to get revenge (11)
10. Titian irrationally stopped college education, being naïve (11)
16. Selfless acts from leader of American left? Say, "It is what it is" (8)
18. I avoid violation of causality resulting in death (8)
20. Paul and his three friends triumphed over Paul (7)
21. Is APAC country losing North Island? (6)
23. Strive to be deadly predator with intense feeling (6)
24. Provincial citrus cocktail (6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image: complete grid]

Clue explanations:

> [image: clue explanations]

Thanks to @Stiv for the wordplay of 22A!

Comment: I just realized about 9A: rot13(V gubhtug "bowrpg" jnfa'g qbvat nalguvat, hagvy V ernyvmrq "jr bowrpg" zrnag "gur bowrpg sbez bs 'jr', juvpu vf gur fhowrpg sbez")! Bravo!

Comment: SAUR(-on) in THE US - think Lord of the Rings  :)

Comment: @Stiv Yup, that fits! Somehow I've never seen that series so I guess it just wasn't readily available in my brain lol